# Убрать имя функции в URI CodeIgniter

Tags: ооп, php, uri, codeigniter

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть класс с функцией

```
class Games extends CI_Controller
{
    public function go($name) 
    {
         display_tpl('game');
    }
}
```

Соответственно, чтобы увидеть эту страницу я должен ввести адрес:

**http://game.ru/games/go/name**

Как мне сделать так, чтобы сократить этот адрес до:

**http://game.ru/games/name**

или до:

**http://game.ru/name**

в фреймворке CodeIgniter.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужен [роутинг](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/general/routing.html).  
Скорее всего, правило будет выглядеть так:

    $route[':any'] => 'games/go',

Answer (score 1):

В route нужно писать так

```
$route['/games/:any'] => 'games/go/$1';
$route['/:any'] => 'games/go/$1';
```

Учтите что если прописать

```
$route['/:any'] => 'games/go/$1';
```

В самом начале файла, то все урлы будут обрабатываться именно этим контроллером и именно этой функцией, поэтому лучше прописать эту строку в самом конце файла route

Comment: @webphp, Прописал в конце файла роута:

    $route['game/:num'] = 'game/index/$1';

Немножко поменял класс и вывод, в итоге по адресу
http://game/game/index/7 - всё нормально отображается, все переменные передались в шаблон, а вот по адресу http://game/game/7 - Message: Undefined variable: name
Filename: views/game.php

Переменные теряются, почему так может быть?

Comment: А в функции как передаете в шаблон значения переменных?
На сколько я помню, надо как то так
$data['name'] = $name;
$this->load->view('/application/views/game, $data);

Тогда в шаблоне уже $name будет равна тому что передали в get запросу